# AWS Glue: write a json object to a file using pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Is there a way to write a simple json object to a text or json file from ETL Glue script without having to convert it to a DataFrame? Right now I am using

```
schema = //my schema
row = Row(my_json_object)
df = spark.createDataFrame([row], schema)
df.write.mode('append').json(s3_path)
```

But I would like to avoid creating dataframe and just write out the `my_json_object` to a file in s3.